# Spring boot storing static page: resources vs WebContent

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have to work on a new project with Spring Boot/angularJS and I have to use web.xml with it.

I know the default location for static resources (for example: js,css, etc) is  src/main/java/resources/static (red box in the screenshot), but how is it different creating my own folder structure directly under WebContent?

[image]

Comment: WebContent is the place where you would store webapp resources in a Java EE web project built with Eclipse (i.e. without real build tool like Maven or gradle). But you've chosen to use the Maven/gradle conventions, so you shouldn't even have a WebContent directory. Maven and gradle conventions put web resources under src/main/webapp.

Comment: oh thanks.. I was just following a tutorial to build a basic template project and I may have created those folder by accident. So, would it be okay for me to just remove it from the project?

Comment: Also... one more question out of topic.. I have to use web.xml to use custom built security filter that i have no control over.. Based on some of the basic readings, it seems like spring boot does not use web.xml. Is it possible throw some configuration to filter mapping using web.xml in boot? thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do that programmatically. But if you deploy as a war file, you may also use a web.xml.

Comment: A related question you should be considering is whether you want your Spring Boot app to be serving your static content, or whether it might be a better idea to serve it from somewhere else like Apache or Nginx. If your final deployment approach is comprised of many Spring Boot services, all individually deployable, which one serves your static content in that picture?

Comment: Hello. Just want to share few things that I learned. if I compile and deploy my app as a war file, web.xml is automatically picked up as answered above. Also I noticed that when I use eclipse to auto deploy to my local server, eclipse keeps making that webcontent folder and pick up .xml files from the folder for my local environment. just wanted to share.